# Django class based views - return HTTPResponse

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Why doesn't this work and it returns `ValueError` instead? I'm trying to get an input from the user and then, depending on the choice the user makes, render a specific view. If i move `return redirect()` back inside `post function` it does work.

```
class Choice(View):

        form_class = SomeForm
        template_name = 'app/object_form.html'

        def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs):

             form = self.form_class()
             return render (request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

        def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

             form = self.form_class(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                 self.redirect_to_createform(request,form.cleaned_data['choice'])

             else:
                print('form not valid')
                print(form.errors)
                return render (request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

        def redirect_to_createform(self, request, option):

            print(option)
            ## Here i should have some logic to redirect to different views depending on the `option`
            return redirect('to_somewhere')
```

Edit - I understand what the error means but how can i achieve the above mentioned goal.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing return statement as below

```
        if form.is_valid():
           return self.redirect_to_createform(request,form.cleaned_data['choice'])
```

Comment: Yes, i hate myself right now:)). Thx, i'll accept the answer as soon as the 10 mins elapse. Thx.